# Remove a href from this code

Tags: custom-taxonomy, links, terms

I am using a short piece of code(which is modified, originally it was a plugin-Taxonomy Terms List) to display custom taxonomies after the post,

When the terms are displayed, it is displayed with a `href` tag.
I don't want the terms to be a link, I just want simple terms text.

How can I get that?

Here is my current code:

```
if( !function_exists( 'pr' ) ) {
    function pr1( $var ) {
        print '<pre>' . print_r( $var, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}

if( !function_exists( 'mfields_taxonomy_terms_list1' ) ) {
    function mfields_taxonomy_terms_list1( $c ) {
        global $post;
        $o = '';

        $terms = array();
        $lists = array();
        $custom_taxonomy_names = array();
        $custom_taxonomies = mfields_get_custom_taxonomies1();

        if( !empty( $custom_taxonomies ) )
            foreach( $custom_taxonomies as $name => $config )
                $custom_taxonomy_names[] = $config->name;

        if( !empty( $custom_taxonomy_names ) )
            $terms = get_terms( $custom_taxonomy_names );

        foreach( $custom_taxonomies as $name => $config )
            $o.= get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $name, $before = '', $sep = ' | ', $after = '' );

        if( is_single() )
            return $c . $o;

        return $c;
    }

    add_shortcode('terms1', 'mfields_taxonomy_terms_list1');
}

if( !function_exists( 'mfields_get_custom_taxonomies1' ) ) {
    function mfields_get_custom_taxonomies1( ) {
        global $wp_taxonomies;

        $custom_taxonomies = array();
        $default_taxonomies = array( 'post_tag', 'category', 'link_category' );

        foreach( $wp_taxonomies as $slug => $config ) 
            if( !in_array( $slug, $default_taxonomies ) )
                $custom_taxonomies[$slug] = $config;

        return $custom_taxonomies;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'enqueue_slideout' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use get_the_terms() instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

This just gives you an array of the associated terms. Then use that array to create your own list without links.